# ECS Container Environment Configuration

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I have a recently-Dockerized web app that I would like to get running on AWS ECS, and a few fundamental concepts (which I don't see explained in the AWS docs) are throwing me off.

First, when you Edit/configure a new container, it asks you to specify the image to use, but then also has an **Environment** section:

[image]

The *Entry point*, *Command* and *Working directory* fields look suspiciously similar to the commands I already specified when creating my Docker image (here's my `Dockerfile`):

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN mkdir /opt/myapp

ADD build/libs/myapp.jar /opt/myapp
WORKDIR /opt/myapp
EXPOSE 9200
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dspring.config=.", "-jar", "myapp.jar"]
```

So if ECS is asking me for an image (that's already been built using this Dockerfile), why in tarnation do I need to re-specify the exact same values for `WORKDIR`, `EXPOSE`, `ENTRYPOINT`, `CMD`, etc.?!?

Also outside of ECS I run my container like so:

```
docker run -it -p 9200:9200 -d --net="host" --env-file ~/myapp-local.env --name myapp myapp
```

Notice how I specify the env file? Does ECS support env files, or do I really have to enter each and every env var from my env file into this UI here?

Also I see there is a *Docker Labels* section near the bottom:

[image]

Are these different than env vars, or are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to add environment variable either through UI or through CLI .

For CLI you need to pass it as JSON template .

Also if you have already specified these values in Dockerfile then you dont need to pass these values again.

All the values that will be passed externally will overwrite internal/default values in Dockerfile